# s3 DeleteObjectsAsync does not work, it stops

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, delete-row

Hi I am using this `DeleteObjectsAsync` and it doesn't work in a way that it looks like it stops, and it doesn't execute the next line and nothing is deleted.

I added try catch but it isn't going to any of the catches. But if I use the non-async one DeleteObjects, it works but I had to put a `.Wait()` like this `client.DeleteObjects(deleteObjectRequest).Wait()` otherwise it stops also like the DeleteObjectsAsync. It stops in a way that the RUN is still on but it just flickers after calling the delete and will not execute the next lines of codes as if it already reached the last line of it. How to make this work? thanks

My code

```
 public static async Task<bool> DeleteFilesFromS3Async(List<KeyVersion> keyVersions, string bucketName = "")
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(AmazonKey, AmazonSecretKey, AmazonRegion))
                {
                    var deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest { BucketName = bucketName , Objects = keyVersions };
                    await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(deleteObjectRequest);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (DeleteObjectsException e)
            {

                return false;
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
              
                return false;
            }
           
            catch (Exception x)
            {
           
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you please add complete method including it's name and return time in code snippet?

Comment: Try to print out the error, just before you would return false in each of the try/catch, that could help

Comment: I did, in original code there's console.writeline there. As I've said it is not even hitting the catch and "return true". it just flickers right after that line  await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(deleteObjectRequest);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling it the right way.

Either, caller method must be `async` and you must be using `await` there.

```
public async Task DeleteFile()
{
  var result = await DeleteFilesFromS3Async(...);
}
```

Or, invoke this method synchronously.

```
public void DeleteFile()
{
  var result = DeleteFilesFromS3Async(...).Result;
}
```